# Funky UV projection render result

Tags: rendering, uv, export, transparency, uv-image-editor

I modeled a phone with a screen behind a glass texture. The screen has been smart UV projected and I put a short 250 frame clip on it. I then animated the phone to spin with glee. Looks great in the view ports I'm super proud wanna show the fam.(note this is a zoomed out view look at that cute li'l phone)[image] However when I render the animation the background gets super messy about 20 frames in. Upon zooming the camera out I have spotted that a second projection of the screen randomly swoops into frame causing the issue as you can see in the image. 
How do I remove or turn off this second projection? 
What is causing this?
Super frustrating.[image]

Comment: By any chance, do you have a second phone object in your scene ? It  looks like it is just a copy which was left behind...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE. Please share your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can take a look :).

Comment: Kriss This was exactly the issue! I had hidden the collection it was in and told the collection not to render but not the items inside! thanks a bunch have a great night.